# Can someone help me recreate this plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, scatter-plot

I am struggling to understand this plot in terms of reproducing the results. Number of rows may point to "Number of Posts" and **Interactions** here refer to number of likes/comments on ONE post.

[image]

How do I perform the calculation to reproduce this graph given that I have a dataset which looks something like this:

```
# For reproducibility
set.seed(12345)

# Define some test data
df <- tibble(
        like=floor(rnorm(200000, 500, 100)), 
        comment=floor(rnorm(200000, 500, 100))
      )
```

So far, I've been able to do the following:

```
#caculate interaction matrix for questionable
library(tidyverse)
df_new <- lapply(
  # For powers of 10
  1:14,
  # Apply this function
  function(n) {
    df%>% 
      # Take the first 10^n rows
      head(2^n) %>% 
      # Calculate column means
      summarise(
        like=sum(like),
        comment=sum(comment),
        .groups="drop"
      ) %>% 
      # Add the index column
      add_column(No_of_rows=2^n, .before=1)
  }
) %>% 
  # Concatenate the results
  bind_rows()
```

After transforming the data, I am using the following command to create the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
df_new %>% pivot_longer(., - No_of_rows, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Value, y = No_of_rows, color = Variable))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  theme_bw()
```

And it is giving me something like this:

[image]

And I am not sure if I am making the right calculations, can someone please help?

Comment: Looks like your question is rather about how to do the calculation than how to plot the data. Please edit your question accordingly and add an example of your expected output (of the calculation).